# JNLP at runtime using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jnlp, java-web-start

I have created  a java web application and I had one window application now I want to load window application using JNLP  (java web start ) and it loads from jsp page at runtime.How can I do this.?

Comment: it's easy, just write your jsp in a way you'd write your jnlp, where the dynamic parts would be scripted by jsp. I think that you anyway need to understand/learn jnlp syntax.

Comment: 1) Go through each of the links on the [JWS tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) 2) When you have a specific question based on that research, come to SO to ask it.